# Ordering of object members

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

I notice that in Javascript (on Chrome, at least) objects remember the order of their members.  For example, in

```
var foo = { x: 1, y: 2 }
var bar = { y: 2, x: 1 }
```

`foo` and `bar` are distinguishable by the order the keys appear when I iterate over them.

My questions are:

1. Is this behavior specified by the standard, or should it be considered an implementation detail?
2. If it is specified by the standard, is there a way to change the order?

Comment: What do you need to change the order for?

Comment: @zerkms, seriously?  My application uses a sorted dictionary where the sort order is modifiable.  I can simulate it by storing the order alongside the dictionary, I was just wondering whether I needed to.

Answer (score 3):

Objects properties are not sorted. The behaviour is implementation-dependent.

However, most JS engines seem to keep the order that was used in an object literal nowadays.

V8/Chrome didn't do so some time ago though.

Comment: Though it sounds correct, can you give a reference to an official source saying it?

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf - I'll add a better reference later, but with a dns-tunnel connection downloading that document will take some time.

Comment: Cool. **+1**. Didn't want vote on an answer that I wasn't sure is correct

Comment: `An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method.`

Comment: 12.6.4: *The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties ... is not specified.*